# When does OpenID Connect return JSON?

Tags: authentication, authorization, jwt, openid-connect

Whereas OAuth2 doesn't explicitly define which token type to use, OpenID Connect defines an API and data format to perform OAuth2 authorization flows.

What are the occasions in which a JWT is returned in OpenID Connect?

Answer (score 2):

> **Authorization flow:** the client requests an authorization code to the authorization endpoint (`/authorize`). This code can be used againt
>   the token endpoint (`/token`) to request an ID token (in JWT format), an
>   access token or a refresh token.
>
> **Implicit flow:** the client requests tokens directly from the authorization endpoint (`/authorize`). The tokens are specified in the
>   request. If an ID token is requested, is is returned in JWT format.
>
> **Hybrid flow:** the client requests both an authorization code and certain tokens from the authorization endpoint (`/authorize`). If an ID
>   token is requested, it is returned in JWT format. If an ID token is
>   not requested at this step, it may later by requested directly from
>   the token endpoint (`/token`).

Source: Sebastián E. Peyrott, Auth0 Inc.  The JWT Handbook (Kindle Locations 262-269). Kindle Edition.